# is it OK to upload your employer's reference letter to the internet and put it public?

Tags: resume, references

I just left my job at one of the Big 4 and I like the reference letter that they wrote about me when leaving.

I maintain an online portfolio / CV / blog. Is it acceptable to put such reference letters on the public internet, or is there a reason not to do that?

Comment: Have you asked the person who wrote the letter?

Comment: I would just include it with any resumes you submit, if you feel it adds enough value.

Comment: Consider asking for LinkedIn recommendation if you want them public

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say in almost every circumstance, **NO**

The reason being is that the internet is forever, and while this was a reference given to you freely, your past employer may take a dim view, especially if you have not asked for permission.

Furthermore, if I saw it, I'd consider it to be unprofessional, even if you did have permission.  References are to be provided when requested, and at no other time.  Most employers don't even want to see them on a resume or in a cover letter unless requested.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not.

Consider yourself lucky that the company gave you such a reference - the rule these days is for HR to only confirm dates of employment, official title when last employed, and a yes/no answer if asked would they employ you again. Anything else leaves them open to legal liability issues.

As an employer.. I have HR contact references to get the above information. If the candidate supplies an open reference letter, it's pretty much ignored; some people will write anything down to make their friends happy.

Comment: The one time when I would consider a reference letter to hold value would be in a circumstance where there was an existing relationship, i.e. where the person writing the letter was known to the person receiving it (the hiring manager). I agree that in the generic case they're generally ignored.